# Error:'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions when using rowMeans() in a large dataframe

Tags: r

This is the dataframe I'm working with:

```
> dput(act.byDay)
list(`6/20/2018` = c(`0` = 59L, `1` = 74L, `2` = 2683L, `3` = 4341L, 
`4` = 3676L, `5` = 2143L, `6` = 3890L, `7` = 3887L, `8` = 1299L, 
`9` = 1492L, `10` = 3449L, `11` = 2200L, `12` = 1563L, `13` = 4346L, 
`14` = 5329L, `15` = 3037L, `16` = 1462L, `17` = 668L, `18` = 383L, 
`19` = 483L, `20` = 288L, `21` = 2765L, `22` = 3354L, `23` = 1783L
), `6/21/2018` = c(`0` = 241L, `1` = 301L, `2` = 261L, `3` = 3683L, 
`4` = 4356L, `5` = 3736L, `6` = 2810L, `7` = 1841L, `8` = 3146L, 
`9` = 609L, `10` = 2998L, `11` = 4059L, `12` = 3690L, `13` = 3735L, 
`14` = 1343L, `15` = 2087L, `16` = 894L, `17` = 341L, `18` = 240L, 
`19` = 2113L, `20` = 1684L, `21` = 3115L, `22` = 2890L, `23` = 138L
), `6/22/2018` = c(`0` = 21L, `1` = 451L, `2` = 96L, `3` = 2918L, 
`4` = 2279L, `5` = 2282L, `6` = 4992L, `7` = 698L, `8` = 427L, 
`9` = 581L, `10` = 1248L, `11` = 2184L, `12` = 1980L, `13` = 2364L, 
`14` = 568L, `15` = 2477L, `16` = 525L, `17` = 433L, `18` = 974L, 
`19` = 501L, `20` = 760L, `21` = 67L, `22` = 297L, `23` = 1198L
), `6/23/2018` = c(`0` = 2L, `1` = 39L, `2` = 42L, `3` = 1182L, 
`4` = 1749L, `5` = 2144L, `6` = 3123L, `7` = 1170L, `8` = 1641L, 
`9` = 1112L, `10` = 1526L, `11` = 1199L, `12` = 534L, `13` = 1481L, 
`14` = 2388L, `15` = 2756L, `16` = 392L, `17` = 112L, `18` = 390L, 
`19` = 107L, `20` = 709L, `21` = 1122L, `22` = 1562L, `23` = 451L
), `6/24/2018` = c(`0` = 8L, `1` = 74L, `2` = 0L, `3` = 158L, 
`4` = 780L, `5` = 3118L, `6` = 3292L, `7` = 2759L, `8` = 3121L, 
`9` = 2051L, `10` = 2387L, `11` = 900L, `12` = 627L, `13` = 904L, 
`14` = 4283L, `15` = 3726L, `16` = 1273L, `17` = 977L, `18` = 326L, 
`19` = 163L, `20` = 1915L, `21` = 1073L, `22` = 1021L, `23` = 545L
), `6/25/2018` = c(`0` = 36L, `1` = 22L, `2` = 3L, `3` = 55L, 
`4` = 124L, `5` = 22L, `6` = 4093L, `7` = 2867L, `8` = 3649L, 
`9` = 2550L, `10` = 1590L, `11` = 636L, `12` = 2571L, `13` = 998L, 
`14` = 1066L, `15` = 2967L, `16` = 1211L, `17` = 51L, `18` = 1188L, 
`19` = 1413L, `20` = 714L, `21` = 177L, `22` = 132L, `23` = 29L
), `6/26/2018` = c(`0` = 22L, `1` = 43L, `2` = 0L, `3` = 90L, 
`4` = 1094L, `5` = 1655L, `6` = 2643L, `7` = 2108L, `8` = 2249L, 
`9` = 2453L, `10` = 2857L, `11` = 915L, `12` = 437L, `13` = 1142L, 
`14` = 2193L, `15` = 2993L, `16` = 1139L, `17` = 1549L, `18` = 652L, 
`19` = 580L, `20` = 970L, `21` = 674L, `22` = 211L, `23` = 206L
), `6/27/2018` = c(`0` = 167L, `1` = 63L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 786L, 
`4` = 617L, `5` = 1575L, `6` = 2237L, `7` = 1302L, `8` = 1149L, 
`9` = 2009L, `10` = 2234L, `11` = 1263L, `12` = 1259L, `13` = 2017L, 
`14` = 1641L, `15` = 2683L, `16` = 1184L, `17` = 449L, `18` = 65L, 
`19` = 956L, `20` = 1538L, `21` = 1287L, `22` = 593L, `23` = 362L
), `6/28/2018` = c(`0` = 594L, `1` = 1172L, `2` = 25L, `3` = 445L, 
`4` = 921L, `5` = 1812L, `6` = 2235L, `7` = 1153L, `8` = 422L, 
`9` = 1084L, `10` = 2158L, `11` = 1610L, `12` = 845L, `13` = 1187L, 
`14` = 2528L, `15` = 2161L, `16` = 976L, `17` = 19L, `18` = 747L, 
`19` = 570L, `20` = 576L, `21` = 19L, `22` = 304L, `23` = 2L), 
    `6/29/2018` = c(`0` = 301L, `1` = 7L, `2` = 399L, `3` = 494L, 
    `4` = 723L, `5` = 1088L, `6` = 771L, `7` = 85L, `8` = 1338L, 
    `9` = 866L, `10` = 384L, `11` = 1356L, `12` = 2862L, `13` = 3805L, 
    `14` = 2142L, `15` = 1655L, `16` = 249L, `17` = 235L, `18` = 3L, 
    `19` = 0L, `20` = 283L, `21` = 981L, `22` = 634L, `23` = 1370L
    ), `6/30/2018` = c(`0` = 9L, `1` = 137L, `2` = 33L, `3` = 975L, 
    `4` = 1690L, `5` = 1639L, `6` = 985L, `7` = 210L, `8` = 1266L, 
    `9` = 2135L, `10` = 2080L, `11` = 1704L, `12` = 2449L, `13` = 3133L, 
    `14` = 1055L, `15` = 3222L, `16` = 1152L, `17` = 173L, `18` = 858L, 
    `19` = 188L, `20` = 700L, `21` = 330L, `22` = 905L, `23` = 1232L
    ), `7/1/2018` = c(`0` = 1006L, `1` = 5L, `2` = 21L, `3` = 520L, 
    `4` = 1162L, `5` = 1771L, `6` = 2463L, `7` = 1403L, `8` = 1353L, 
    `9` = 1938L, `10` = 2388L, `11` = 4133L, `12` = 900L, `13` = 2660L, 
    `14` = 3504L, `15` = 3946L, `16` = 1956L, `17` = 818L, `18` = 604L, 
    `19` = 937L, `20` = 373L, `21` = 48L, `22` = 400L, `23` = 201L
    ), `7/10/2018` = c(`0` = 705L, `1` = 47L, `2` = 605L, `3` = 257L, 
    `4` = 1359L, `5` = 41L, `6` = 1019L, `7` = 1426L, `8` = 2219L, 
    `9` = 1179L, `10` = 1624L, `11` = 537L, `12` = 421L, `13` = 1747L, 
    `14` = 2941L, `15` = 2921L, `16` = 1046L, `17` = 283L, `18` = 476L, 
    `19` = 218L, `20` = 59L, `21` = 389L, `22` = 657L, `23` = 1293L
    ), `7/11/2018` = c(`0` = 24L, `1` = 455L, `2` = 6L, `3` = 1232L, 
    `4` = 2264L, `5` = 1152L, `6` = 600L, `7` = 11L, `8` = 980L, 
    `9` = 1519L, `10` = 2004L, `11` = 1933L, `12` = 2161L, `13` = 1386L, 
    `14` = 1883L, `15` = 2978L, `16` = 1385L, `17` = 104L, `18` = 1309L, 
    `19` = 2L, `20` = 364L, `21` = 550L, `22` = 0L, `23` = 1433L
    ), `7/12/2018` = c(`0` = 1634L, `1` = 27L, `2` = 860L, `3` = 1095L, 
    `4` = 1102L, `5` = 132L, `6` = 582L, `7` = 710L, `8` = 1368L, 
    `9` = 2470L, `10` = 2944L, `11` = 1030L, `12` = 1286L, `13` = 387L, 
    `14` = 2590L, `15` = 2449L, `16` = 743L, `17` = 134L, `18` = 274L, 
    `19` = 205L, `20` = 360L, `21` = 627L, `22` = 1357L, `23` = 591L
    ), `7/13/2018` = c(`0` = 216L, `1` = 143L, `2` = 70L, `3` = 2L, 
    `4` = 477L, `5` = 42L, `6` = 81L, `7` = 304L, `8` = 2827L, 
    `9` = 2437L, `10` = 2002L, `11` = 688L, `12` = 935L, `13` = 812L, 
    `14` = 404L, `15` = 1098L, `16` = 1157L, `17` = 857L, `18` = 466L, 
    `19` = 215L, `20` = 714L, `21` = 269L, `22` = 1223L, `23` = 8L
    ), `7/14/2018` = c(`0` = 1L, `1` = 635L, `2` = 6L, `3` = 1797L, 
    `4` = 1363L, `5` = 246L, `6` = 704L, `7` = 1089L, `8` = 943L, 
    `9` = 2251L, `10` = 813L, `11` = 2643L, `12` = 1657L, `13` = 18L, 
    `14` = 1132L, `15` = 2884L, `16` = 1044L, `17` = 149L, `18` = 1146L, 
    `19` = 68L, `20` = 1227L, `21` = 1189L, `22` = 129L, `23` = 1291L
    ), `7/15/2018` = c(`0` = 7L, `1` = 9L, `2` = 1299L, `3` = 389L, 
    `4` = 288L, `5` = 157L, `6` = 0L, `7` = 324L, `8` = 248L, 
    `9` = 915L, `10` = 795L, `11` = 598L, `12` = 733L, `13` = 308L, 
    `14` = 2760L, `15` = 2874L, `16` = 1903L, `17` = 499L, `18` = 73L, 
    `19` = 31L, `20` = 1146L, `21` = 920L, `22` = 852L, `23` = 2L
    ), `7/16/2018` = c(`0` = 104L, `1` = 564L, `2` = 16L, `3` = 1903L, 
    `4` = 675L, `5` = 1859L, `6` = 720L, `7` = 1017L, `8` = 4L, 
    `9` = 2114L, `10` = 2264L, `11` = 1152L, `12` = 935L, `13` = 1691L, 
    `14` = 1031L, `15` = 2568L, `16` = 2035L, `17` = 226L, `18` = 18L, 
    `19` = 1716L, `20` = 249L, `21` = 717L, `22` = 635L, `23` = 919L
    ), `7/17/2018` = c(`0` = 1436L, `1` = 16L, `2` = 17L, `3` = 1891L, 
    `4` = 1175L, `5` = 74L, `6` = 435L, `7` = 377L, `8` = 718L, 
    `9` = 619L, `10` = 439L, `11` = 1373L, `12` = 2154L, `13` = 2481L, 
    `14` = 763L, `15` = 2084L, `16` = 910L, `17` = 641L, `18` = 669L, 
    `19` = 737L, `20` = 793L, `21` = 1471L, `22` = 12L, `23` = 96L
    ), `7/18/2018` = c(`0` = 6L, `1` = 13L, `2` = 81L, `3` = 1227L, 
    `4` = 1685L, `5` = 260L, `6` = 238L, `7` = 575L, `8` = 930L, 
    `9` = 330L, `10` = 1139L, `11` = 785L, `12` = 1110L, `13` = 1007L, 
    `14` = 1770L, `15` = 2824L, `16` = 729L, `17` = 776L, `18` = 602L, 
    `19` = 550L, `20` = 1432L, `21` = 567L, `22` = 197L, `23` = 107L
    ), `7/19/2018` = c(`0` = 38L, `1` = 648L, `2` = 264L, `3` = 911L, 
    `4` = 2239L, `5` = 1063L, `6` = 9L, `7` = 1336L, `8` = 1235L, 
    `9` = 628L, `10` = 1722L, `11` = 1028L, `12` = 1393L, `13` = 44L, 
    `14` = 2110L, `15` = 1719L, `16` = 666L, `17` = 127L, `18` = 885L, 
    `19` = 788L, `20` = 1274L, `21` = 765L, `22` = 1094L, `23` = 38L
    ), `7/2/2018` = c(`0` = 876L, `1` = 505L, `2` = 162L, `3` = 775L, 
    `4` = 1567L, `5` = 896L, `6` = 1648L, `7` = 995L, `8` = 2574L, 
    `9` = 1080L, `10` = 997L, `11` = 1881L, `12` = 1375L, `13` = 1283L, 
    `14` = 2156L, `15` = 2384L, `16` = 982L, `17` = 33L, `18` = 20L, 
    `19` = 761L, `20` = 241L, `21` = 696L, `22` = 133L, `23` = 915L
    ), `7/20/2018` = c(`0` = 514L, `1` = 14L, `2` = 59L, `3` = 1081L, 
    `4` = 1266L, `5` = 359L, `6` = 1055L, `7` = 280L, `8` = 123L, 
    `9` = 2251L, `10` = 2302L, `11` = 1116L, `12` = 2750L, `13` = 764L, 
    `14` = 1377L, `15` = 2776L, `16` = 970L, `17` = 814L, `18` = 10L, 
    `19` = 1364L, `20` = 1137L, `21` = 279L, `22` = 10L, `23` = 605L
    ), `7/21/2018` = c(`0` = 279L, `1` = 596L, `2` = 12L, `3` = 1443L, 
    `4` = 1463L, `5` = 1426L, `6` = 132L, `7` = 924L, `8` = 379L, 
    `9` = 693L, `10` = 137L, `11` = 219L, `12` = 884L, `13` = 194L, 
    `14` = 450L, `15` = 1204L, `16` = 487L, `17` = 578L, `18` = 445L, 
    `19` = 9L, `20` = 823L, `21` = 2L, `22` = 1212L, `23` = 12L
    ), `7/22/2018` = c(`0` = 200L, `1` = 9L, `2` = 152L, `3` = 1062L, 
    `4` = 1926L, `5` = 1156L, `6` = 1951L, `7` = 1735L, `8` = 753L, 
    `9` = 570L, `10` = 362L, `11` = 813L, `12` = 756L, `13` = 1403L, 
    `14` = 308L, `15` = 1895L, `16` = 325L, `17` = 768L, `18` = 666L, 
    `19` = 33L, `20` = 634L, `21` = 1294L, `22` = 819L, `23` = 39L
    ), `7/23/2018` = c(`0` = 579L, `1` = 8L, `2` = 657L, `3` = 438L, 
    `4` = 521L, `5` = 896L, `6` = 2560L, `7` = 1383L, `8` = 819L, 
    `9` = 1293L, `10` = 2257L, `11` = 476L, `12` = 1850L, `13` = 759L, 
    `14` = 2482L, `15` = 1513L, `16` = 789L, `17` = 78L, `18` = 329L, 
    `19` = 43L, `20` = 50L, `21` = 1583L, `22` = 342L, `23` = 0L
    ), `7/24/2018` = c(`0` = 0L), `7/3/2018` = c(`0` = 623L, 
    `1` = 918L, `2` = 48L, `3` = 523L, `4` = 721L, `5` = 1624L, 
    `6` = 1047L, `7` = 1783L, `8` = 313L, `9` = 1042L, `10` = 2211L, 
    `11` = 2430L, `12` = 1770L, `13` = 1610L, `14` = 2814L, `15` = 2460L, 
    `16` = 1770L, `17` = 25L, `18` = 709L, `19` = 416L, `20` = 709L, 
    `21` = 998L, `22` = 921L, `23` = 89L), `7/4/2018` = c(`0` = 258L, 
    `1` = 1242L, `2` = 75L, `3` = 1131L, `4` = 893L, `5` = 402L, 
    `6` = 381L, `7` = 51L, `8` = 15L, `9` = 47L, `10` = 762L, 
    `11` = 777L, `12` = 479L, `13` = 2416L, `14` = 3639L, `15` = 1991L, 
    `16` = 202L, `17` = 1054L, `18` = 917L, `19` = 1565L, `20` = 503L, 
    `21` = 61L, `22` = 44L, `23` = 2103L), `7/5/2018` = c(`0` = 2212L, 
    `1` = 352L, `2` = 1L, `3` = 666L, `4` = 351L, `5` = 1321L, 
    `6` = 7L, `7` = 1010L, `8` = 1222L, `9` = 1080L, `10` = 1643L, 
    `11` = 1101L, `12` = 188L, `13` = 2793L, `14` = 1548L, `15` = 1811L, 
    `16` = 1807L, `17` = 51L, `18` = 788L, `19` = 1108L, `20` = 1157L, 
    `21` = 1038L, `22` = 225L, `23` = 454L), `7/6/2018` = c(`0` = 441L, 
    `1` = 376L, `2` = 444L, `3` = 5L, `4` = 501L, `5` = 579L, 
    `6` = 1253L, `7` = 1600L, `8` = 1051L, `9` = 498L, `10` = 2217L, 
    `11` = 2362L, `12` = 2425L, `13` = 1220L, `14` = 2037L, `15` = 2684L, 
    `16` = 799L, `17` = 471L, `18` = 139L, `19` = 545L, `20` = 1117L, 
    `21` = 177L, `22` = 487L, `23` = 1420L), `7/7/2018` = c(`0` = 692L, 
    `1` = 303L, `2` = 736L, `3` = 750L, `4` = 1386L, `5` = 926L, 
    `6` = 30L, `7` = 862L, `8` = 1912L, `9` = 2731L, `10` = 1123L, 
    `11` = 1160L, `12` = 2892L, `13` = 1634L, `14` = 585L, `15` = 3473L, 
    `16` = 2243L, `17` = 441L, `18` = 399L, `19` = 1482L, `20` = 111L, 
    `21` = 455L, `22` = 1315L, `23` = 691L), `7/8/2018` = c(`0` = 1428L, 
    `1` = 96L, `2` = 52L, `3` = 258L, `4` = 1135L, `5` = 1727L, 
    `6` = 448L, `7` = 2148L, `8` = 358L, `9` = 2180L, `10` = 1519L, 
    `11` = 2634L, `12` = 828L, `13` = 1212L, `14` = 1052L, `15` = 2851L, 
    `16` = 902L, `17` = 171L, `18` = 236L, `19` = 3L, `20` = 727L, 
    `21` = 1366L, `22` = 637L, `23` = 43L), `7/9/2018` = c(`0` = 0L, 
    `1` = 1320L, `2` = 146L, `3` = 664L, `4` = 862L, `5` = 663L, 
    `6` = 227L, `7` = 227L, `8` = 995L, `9` = 743L, `10` = 1793L, 
    `11` = 2421L, `12` = 1346L, `13` = 1874L, `14` = 2182L, `15` = 1333L, 
    `16` = 1967L, `17` = 1023L, `18` = 297L, `19` = 340L, `20` = 1469L, 
    `21` = 10L, `22` = 213L, `23` = 805L))
```

The object has several columns with a date on the header and several rows labelling the hour of that date. The values in the table represent average speed measures of an animal for every hour for the days listed in the column headers.

I would like to create a dataframe or to add a column that takes the average for every hour for all days. In other words, this means applying the function `rowMeans()`.

However when using it, I'm getting:

```
> act.byDay$overall <- rowMeans(act.byDay)
Error in rowMeans(act.byDay) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

If somebody knows what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate your help!

Comment: It is a `list` and not a data.frame You need `rowMeans(do.call(rbind, act.byDay))`

Comment: Or just `rowMeans(as.data.frame(l))`, depending on which way the author intends the data and summaries to flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'act.byDay' is a `list` of named `vector`s by checking the structure (`str(act.byDay)`).  We can `rbind` the `vector`s together with `do.call` and then apply `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(do.call(rbind, act.byDay))
```

---

Or as @r2evans mentioned, it could be also

```
rowMeans(as.data.frame(act.byDay))
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP's statement *"average for every hour for all days"* could be interpreted in two ways: if the result should be one value per day (averaging all hours in that day), then this is correct. If the result should return 24 values (each hour of the day), then it should be `rowMeans(as.data.frame(act.byDay))`.